# ODE45 and Runge-Kutta methods with matlab for optimal control about corona

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, numerical-integration, runge-kutta

I would appreciate if someone can help with the following issue. I have the following ODE:

[image]

this is the project that I have worked to create a Matlab code to it

**https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7376536/#Equ1**

the human population
N(t)=S(t)+E(t)+IA(t)+IS(t)+R(t).

Model parameter name    Symbol  Value

```
Birth rate of the human population  b   0.00018 days−1

Natural human death rate    μ   4.563×10−5 days−1

Human life expectancy   1μ  21915 days or 60 years

Natural death rate of pathogens in the environment  μP  0.1724 days−1

Life expectancy of pathogens in the environment 1μP 5.8 days

Proportion of interaction with an infectious environment    α1  0.10

Proportion of interaction with an infectious individual α1  0.10

Rate of transmission from S to E due to contact with P  β1  0.00414

Rate of transmission from S to E due to contact with IA and/or IS   β2  0.0115

Proportion of symptomatic infectious people δ   0.7

Progression rate from E back to S due to robust immune system   ψ   0.0051

Progression rate from E to either IA or IS  ω   0.09

Death rate due to the coronavirus   σ   0.0018

Rate of recovery of the symptomatic population  γS  0.05 days−1 or 120days

Rate of recovery of the asymptomatic human population   γA  0.0714 days−1

Rate of virus spread to environment by symptomatic infectious individuals   ηS  0.1 days−1 or 110days

Rate of virus spread to environment by asymptomatic infectious individuals  ηA  0.05 days−1 or 120days
```

I'm trying to solve a system of coupled ODEs using a 4th-order Runge-Kutta method for my project work in Matlab .

I'm stuck in first loop , can't understand what next steps to use k1,k2,k3,k4 in the method

```
function y = code(S0,E0,IA0,IS0,R0,P0)

% Birth rate of the human population     
b= 0.00018;

% Natural human death rate 
u = 0.00004563

% Human Life expectancy
inverse_u = 1/u;

% Natural deapth rate of pathogens in the environment
up= 0.1724;

%Life expectancy of pathogens in environment
inverse_up = 1/up;

%Proportion of interaction with an infectious environment
a1= 0.1;

% Proportion of interaction with an infectious individual
a2= 0.1;

% Rate of transmission from S to E  due to contact with P
B1= 0.00414;

% Rate of transmission from S to E  due to contact with Ι_Α and/or Ι_S
B2= 0.0115;

% δ Proportion of symptomatic infectious people
Delta = 0.7;

%ψ Progression rate from E back to S due to robust immune system
psi =  0.0051;

% ω Progression rate from E to either Ι_Αor Ι_S
Omega =  0.09;

% σ  Death rate due to the Coronavirus
Sigma = 0.0018

% νs Rate of recovery of the symptomatic population

Vs = 0.05;

% νa Rate of recovery of the symptomatic human population

Va = 0.0714;

% ηs Rate of virus spread to environment by symptomatic infectious individuals
Eta_s = 0.1;

% ηa  Rate of virus spread to environment by asymptomatic infectious individuals
Eta_a = 0.1;

test = -1;

delta = 0.001;
M = 90;
t=linspace(0,10,M+1);
h=1/M;
h2 = h/2;

S=zeros(1,M+1);
E=zeros(1,M+1);
IA=zeros(1,M+1);
IS=zeros(1,M+1);
R=zeros(1,M+1);
P=zeros(1,M+1);


S(1)=S0;
E(1)=E0;
IA(1)=IA0;
IS(1)= IS0;
R(1)=R0;
P(1)=P0;

 %() = () + () +() + () + ().
N(1)=S0+E0+IA0+IS0+R0

lambda1=zeros(1,M+1);
lambda2=zeros(1,M+1);
lambda3=zeros(1,M+1);
lambda4=zeros(1,M+1);
lambda5=zeros(1,M+1);

while(test < 0)
    
    oldP = P;
    oldS = S;
    oldE = E;
    oldIA = IA;
    oldIS = IS;
    oldR = R;
    oldN = N;
    oldlambda1 = lambda1;
    oldlambda2 = lambda2;
    oldlambda3 = lambda3;
    oldlambda4 = lambda4;
     oldlambda5 =lambda5;   

    for i = 1:M
        m11 = b -( ( B1 *S(i)*P(i) ) / (1+a1*P(i) ) )  - ( ( B2*S(i) *(IA(i) + IS(i) )  ) / ( 1+a2*(IA(i) + IS(i))  ) ) + psi*E(i) - u*S(i) ;
        m12 =   ( ( B1 *S(i)*P(i) ) / (1+a1*P(i) ) ) +  ( ( B2*S(i) *(IA(i) + IS(i) )  ) / ( 1+a2*(IA(i) + IS(i))  ) )  -psi*E(i)   - u*E(i) - Omega *E(i);
        m13 = (1 - Sigma ) *Omega*E(i) - (u + Sigma  ) * IA(i) - Va *IA(i) ;
        m14 =  Sigma * Omega*E(i) - ( u + Sigma ) * IS(i) - Vs*IS(i) ;
        m15 = Vs*IS(i) +  Va *IA(i) - u*R(i) ;
        m16 =  Eta_a * IA(i) +  Eta_s * IS(i) - up*P(i);
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408704/solve-a-system-of-equations-with-runge-kutta-4-matlab/43410394#43410394) for a generic RK4 function. Currently your question is too broad, "I can't understand the next steps" is not specific enough to be on-topic, please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see , the equation are coupled , so the best way to deal with them in a matrix form or use the method mention at this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LzDiScAcJI